# Unable to reproduce Monoid examples from shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I try to reproduce the Monoid examples from: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/monoids.scala

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import MonoidSyntax._
<console>:10: error: not found: value MonoidSyntax
       import MonoidSyntax._
          ^

scala> import Monoid.auto._
<console>:10: error: not found: value Monoid
       import Monoid.auto._
```

I tried with Shapeless-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and Shapeless-2.0.0-M1. Do i need some other things?

Thanks 
Fabian

Comment: This doesn't really feel like a SO question. Even if the problem had not been caused by you missing a part of the example, it doesn't seem like the knowledge could be generalized much from an answer.

Comment: The only knowledge you can gain from my question is that you should read the complete example... I think this question could be delted. (I don't know how to delete a question)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i missed the Monoid part of the example...